# Routing is not working properly

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have created an angular 2 app. And here is the `app.routes.ts`

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RoleListComponent } from './role-list.component';
import { RoleEditComponent } from './role-edit.component';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'role-list', component: RoleListComponent
    }

    , {
        path: 'role-edit', component: RoleEditComponent
    }
    , {
        path: '', redirectTo: '/role-list', pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

There are two buttons on the screen that navigates to that pages.
And then I configured proxy using `http-proxy-middleware` in `bs-config.js`

**bs-config.js**

```
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

var apiProxy = proxy('/services', {
    target: 'http://localhost:9000',
    changeOrigin: true
});

module.exports = {
    port: 9001,
    server: {
        baseDir: "src",
        routes: {
            "/node_modules": "node_modules"
        },
        middleware: {
            1: apiProxy,
        }
    }
};
```

Now when I start my application it hits the `http://localhost:9001/role-list` and  shows error message on screen

```
Cannot GET /role-list
```

If I hit `localhost:9001` then it works and shows the `http://localhost:9001/role-list` URL in the address bar but if I hit the same URL directly it shows the above error.

Now if I remove the proxy middleware it works fine. I am not able to understand what is the issue? Am I configuring something wrong? What could be the possible issue?

Comment: That's probably because the server (proxy) doesn't support HTML5 pushState. You can try to add `useHash: true` to your router configuration (you'll get a different URL, but if it works this way it verifies my assumption)

Comment: Thanks !! this works but hash is showing in my url and I dont want that. Is there any other solution of this?

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, this is only to verify. You need a server that supports HTML5 pushState, or configure the server you have to support it. I don't know about your server, but there are lots of answers to all kind of servers.

Comment: The whole configuration story is about the server returning `index.html` if the client requests an unknown resource

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on the server-side.

You need to route (**on the server side**) every Angular route to the base path specified in `index.html`. For example, this is how it is done in `nodeJS`:

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {req, res});
});
```

or `Apache`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Otherwise, when your customer will reach for example `www.example.com/path/someThing` your server will be looking for `index.html` file in the `/var/www/example.com/path/someThing/` instead of `/var/www/example.com/`